# How to read console output in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, console, stdout

i want to read the data from console(cmd) i tried this code

```
compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
compiler.Start();
compiler.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

but its not working

Comment: define **not working**.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Process compiler = new Process();
compiler.StartInfo.FileName = "SOME.exe";
compiler.StartInfo.Arguments = "SOME ARG";
compiler.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
compiler.Start();    

var result=compiler.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

compiler.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: That may hang. Use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032643/get-values-from-process-standardoutput