# Why doesn't process run on ms server 2003 and iis6?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-6, windows-server-2003

I'm trying to run process on ms server 2003 and iis 6, but it isn't avail.

```
Process _process = new Process();
_process.StartInfo.FileName = Server.MapPath("~/Content/vtourPolygon/krpanotools/kmakemultires.exe");
_process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
_process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

string templatePath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/vtourPolygon/krpanotools/templates/normal.config");
string imagePath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/vtourPolygon/image.jpg");
_process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("krpanotools makepano -config={0} {1}", templatePath, imagePath);
_process.Start();
_process.WaitForExit();
```

What's the problem

Comment: Well what happens when you try? Do you get an exception? Does the executable just not run?

Comment: Have you considered that 2003 is just terrifically old and the application may not run? That instalaltion requirements may miss (like a C++ runtime)? Have you even considered trying to start it from the command line just to check that it does work? Amazing amount of work you did so far - copy,paste, ask others to guess.

Comment: Can you hook up the Output and error stream as shown in [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15032982/578411) and write the result to Trace.Write