# Run cmd line per line

Tags: c#, cmd

I'm writing an application.I want to run process step by step from text variable and then show it on a textbox.
Here my code:

```
void RunCmd(string cmd){
    StringCollection values = new StringCollection();
        p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        p.StartInfo.FileName = @"cmd";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments= cmd;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.Start();

        p.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => {
            lock (values) {
                values.Add(e.Data);
            }
        };

        p.BeginOutputReadLine();
        foreach (string sline in values)
            txtresult.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + sline);
}

void btnAction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RunCmd("/c test.exe ABC && test.exe A5");
    RunCmd("test.exe 22");
}
```

It not working.Txtresult is empty

Comment: what do you mean by form is hidden??

Comment: `start.CreateNoWindow = true;` will hide your application...

Comment: I mean mainform don't display.I can't see it

Comment: Your sample isn't complete it seems - for example RunCmd is declared as without any params but you're passing in a string ?

Comment: I suspect reader.ReadToEnd() is blocking - have you tried putting a breakpoint on that line and seeing if that's the case ? Does result contain anything ?

Comment: yes,string result is null.Any idea

Comment: You may need to modify your code along the lines of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032643/get-values-from-process-standardoutput