# How can I call exe static method & get value?

Tags: c#, command-line-interface, exe

My exe code like this:

```
class Program
    {
        //here I want to call
        static int ADD(int a , int b){return a+b};
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
```

My other project call exe by Progress like :

```
Process p = new Process();
                p.StartInfo.Arguments = sb.ToString();
                p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                p.StartInfo.FileName = "Myexe.exe";
                p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
                p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                p.Start();
```

I knew I can set args[] to do something , But how can I invoke some method & return value ,

for example "ADD(1+1)"

Maybe it can send message back or get output? , I don't know.

Comment: AFAIK You can't launch an executable like that and specifically target a method without setting arguments to effect that.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is this..In your exe you have code like this:

```
public class CalledExe
{
    public static void ADD(int a, int b) { Console.WriteLine( a + b); }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a, b;

        if (args == null && !args.Any())
            return;

        if (args.Count() != 2)
            return;

        if (args.Count() == 2)
            if (int.TryParse(args[0], out a) && int.TryParse(args[1], out b))
                ADD(a, b);

    }//end void function Main

}//end CalledExe class
```

Now, in your calling class:

```
public class CallingExe
{
   public static void main(string[] args)
   {
      System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
      proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"CalledExe.exe";
      proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "1 2";
      proc.Start();
   }
}
```

This will print 3 on the console.

Answer (score 1):

There are two opions:

**Define a command line interface to MyExe**

See also Gauravsa's answer.

```
class Program
{
    static int ADD(int a , int b){return a+b};
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // error handling omitted!
        switch (args[0])
        {
        case "ADD":
            Consle.WriteLine("={0}", ADD(int.Parse(args[1]), int.Parse(args[2)));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

In the calling process, pass "ADD 1 1" to MyExe.exe as command line and read the result from StdOutput (see e.g. [Get Values from Process StandardOutput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032643/get-values-from-process-standardoutput))

**Use the executable as class library**

If it does not need to be in a separate process, you can simply add a reference to Myexe.exe to your project and then call `var result = Program.ADD(1, 2);`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this; process execution:

```
  string result; 

  ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo() {
    EnableRaisingEvents = true, 
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    Arguments = "1 2", // we pass 2 arguments: 1 and 2
    FileName = @"Myexe.exe",
  };

  using (Process process = new Process()) {
    process.StartInfo = info;
    process.Start();

    StringBuilder sbOut = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder sbErr = new StringBuilder();

    process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => {
      if (e.Data != null) {
        sbOut.AppendLine(e.Data);
      }
    };

    process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) => {
      if (e.Data != null)
        sbErr.AppendLine(e.Data);
    };

    process.BeginErrorReadLine();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();

    // Let process complete its work
    process.WaitForExit();

    result = sbErr.Length > 0 
      ? sbErr.ToString()   // process failed, let's have a look at StdErr
      : sbOut.ToString();  // process suceeded, let's get StdOut
  }

  Console.WriteLine(result);
```

When `Myexe` has to read form *command line arguments* (`args`):

```
  static void Main(string[] args) {
    // When given args we parse them...  
    if (args.Length >= 2 && 
        int.TryParse(args[0], out int a) && 
        int.TryParse(args[1], out int b)) 
      Console.WriteLine(a + b); // and return (via StdOut) their sum
    else
      Console.WriteLine($"Failed to execute {string.Join(" ", args)}");  
  }
```