# Can i check if a process asks for an input?

Tags: c#

Hi i want to read a Process.StandardOutput.Readline() until the process asks for input

Pseudo code :

```
while(cmd doesn't asks for input) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.StandardOutput.ReadLine())
}
```

i've already tried

```
while(!p.StandardOutput.EndOfStream) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.StandardOutput.ReadLine())
}
```

but it makes an infinite loop because the process asks for input

thanks in advance :)

Comment: If the process outputs: *Please enter name:* (or what ever it puts on the outputstream) you'll find that text when you do a ReadLine(). When you do, act accordingly. There is no other magic to help you out.

Comment: You seem to be looking for something that will never end anyway. Inputs are part of the stream, the `p.StandardOutput.ReadLine()` is waiting for something to be written to the stream so it can read it.

Comment: Do know that you probably need to handle the datareceived events, instead of looping: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032643/get-values-from-process-standardoutput/15032982#15032982

Comment: Thanks a lot Rene you solved my problem ;)